# How to format this IP list?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, regular-expression

I have a comma-separated list in this rather simple format:

```
IPrangestart,IPrangeend,int number,date (delimited by slashes),Name (is dirty, contains spaces, dots, dashes, quotemarks etc)
```

The first three columns can't be empty.
I want to to transform this to a standard firewall blocking viable format denoting the random separated by a dash:

```
IPrangestart-IPrangend
```

Sometimes the fields are empty.
What's the quickest and smartest way to do this for thousands of lines?
I tried RegEx like [A-Za-z] for each letter and [0-9] for each number, but that doesn't solve the issues with the random " . and similar stuff specified above...

I tried this RegEx but I don't know how to make it recognize the dash in between `(\b25[0-5]|\b2[0-4][0-9]|\b[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}`

Comment: Which fields can empty? The first two? `IPrangestart` and `IPrangeend`?

Comment: No, the first three columns are always there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the ip related columns are always there (Based on your comment) use `cut` to keep the first two comma separated columns, and replace `,` with a `-`:

```
cut -d, -f1,2 --output-delimiter=-
```

---

If, for some reason, you haven't got access to `GNU cut` from `coreutils`(Thing which i doubt since you tagged the question with `linux`) and therefore you are missing the `--output-delimiter = -` option :

```
sed 's/^\([^,]*\),([^,]*).*/\1-\2/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F "," 'BEGIN{OFS="-"}{print $1,$2}' File
```

output

IPrangestart-IPrangeend